# strlen for two or more strings?

Tags: php

Which is the correct way of making strlen return the lenght of several strings put together.

For example if one string is hello and other is jim it should return: 8. (hello=5 jim=3)

I need to get the combined lenght of $array[0] $array[1] $array[2] $array[3] and $array[4]

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use [implode](http://php.net/implode) on it before:

```
echo strlen(implode($array));
```

You can also combine it with [array_slice](http://php.net/array_slice) if you don't want the whole array:

```
echo strlen(implode(array_slice($array, 0, 4)));
```

Comment: Thanks I used the second option

Answer (score 3):

```
array_sum(array_map("strlen", $array_of_strings))
```

Comment: should not we try to avoid `array_map` in such cases? I am under the impression that `array_map` produces extra overhead!

Comment: @Stoic: from a micro optimization point of view it's a clear: maybe. I can't really say if building a list is slower than instantiating a new string via implode(). This one is only preferable memory-wise.

Comment: @Stoic watch your own solution which is WAY more inefficient!!! It's really stupid to concatenate string if you need only length.

Comment: @shrapnel.. if you do a stopwatch on the codes.. it turns out my code is taking half the time for 100000 runs on my system.. i dont understand why you would say inefficient. (and, no its not directed to you @mario.. i had a genuine query with my comment on your answer) :(

Comment: @Stoic: It really depends on the actual use case. With many very very short strings the concatenation /*might*/ be quicker. I don't know. You'll have to run it through xdebug and look at the kcachegrind graphs to get a conclusive answer. It probably won't matter for the OPs use case, anyway :]

Answer (score 2):

```
$len = 0;
foreach($array as $str)
    $len += strlen($str);
```

Comment: `+=` ? This is not INT is STRING

Comment: @Keyne: No it's an integer, he's incrementing the result of `strlen`. However the above code isn't valid. There are some missing `;`.

Comment: Actually, it is an int.  And no, he asked for the total length of multiple strings, not a string.

Comment: @netcoder Now I see =) actually the code is right (with `;`).

Comment: @Phoenix Yes, At first at thought he was counting the lenght of an int. I've mixed up with the Stoic answer. Sorry.

Answer (score 1):

use something like this:

```
$string = '';
foreach ($array as $val) {
    $string .= $val;
}
echo strlen($string);
```

This will avoid multiple `strlen` calls and hence, should be a bit faster then calling `strlen` inside the `foreach` loop, atleast theoretically.

Comment: @Liso22 You could also just concact `strlen($ar[0] . $ar[1] . $ar[2]);`

Comment: the benefit of using `foreach` loop is that you can add any changes you want to be applied to the individual values... if you are only concatenating the array values, you can also use `implode` instead of `foreach` loop.

Comment: Why concatenate all these strings?

Comment: @shrapnel.. because Liso wants `strlen` of array values and add them later. this just calls the `strlen` once, since array values are now concatenated into one string.

Comment: yes. because your solution is stupid and your desire to call strlen once is ridiculous.

Comment: @shrapnel.. lolz. but i am only asking for a reason friend. And, anyway if I can save some extra function calls, its just better, isnt it? rather than calling `strlen` in the `foreach` loop? Please, do a time analysis here, first. saving these extra calls makes my code twice as efficient.

Comment: nope, it isn't better. your idea of code optimization is ridiculous not to say idiotic. I can't educate every lamer on the site, so, you'd better to buy yourself a book. I hope you can read at least.

Comment: hmm.. Probably. I understand what you are coming at. But, honestly, I would just really thank you, if you can let me know a simply `why`. I wont say I am `at all` good. I just thought, if you could give a reason, I would be able to do it correctly, next time, because I dont know where I went wrong and what should I be looking for to correct myself :/

Comment: see, that's really simple. you are doing a string concat with each iteration. it looks like just a little punctuation mark, but it's a rightful operator like strlen(). String concat is not something free So, as a matter of fact you are doing N+1 string operations: N concats + 1 strlen. So, even number of operations is not on your side.

Comment: moreover and most important part: for the OP's case it's negligible, but in case we have considerable amount of data, you will double memory usage with your method and it's way more serious programmer's sin. A further reading from this site founder: http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/fog0000000319.html

Answer (score -1):

You can use [implode()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php) to transform your array of strings in a single string and then strlen the result.

```
echo strlen(implode('', $array))
```

Answer (score -1):

If you want to get the collective length of all of the strings in an array, you can do this:

```
$len = strlen(implode('',$myArray));
```

*Note that this code will join the strings together with no spaces between them. You can change the first parameter to `implode()` if you want this to be different.